# How to list all available locale files in Android app?

Tags: android

How to dynamically list all available locale files in an Android app?

I wish to add the option for the user to override the default locale in my app, and select from a list of the ones I've already created, however did not want to hardcode such a list and having to touch the code for every new localization file I create.

Is it possible to obtain such a listing dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getAssets().getLocales()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#getLocales()) from `Activity`. This is much more prefered way of getting all the `Locales` as it get's the locales that this `AssetManager` contains data for.

OR

You can also use the [Locale.getAvailableLocales()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales()) method, which returns an array of all installed [Locales](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html). It's available in API level 1

Once you get this list you can populate it in a Spinner or any widget you wish.

Comment: Both `getAssets().getLocales()` and `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` return a list of the locales installed on the **system**, but OP was asking of locale resources available in the **app**.